# finding top parent, Tree Traversal: finding active parent in R

Tags: r, regex, match, tree-traversal, stringr

pls review my situation below and since it is complex I tried my best to illustrate it but there could be issues. So pls ask me question and I am very quick to respond.

here is the scenario

Get the top most active parent in the hierarchy

1. Iterate from Child column, for eg. Child 0190 against corresponding list column 0197_0195_0192_0190 (row 6)
2. Then check for previous parent 0192 in the Child Column, which is present.
3. Then check Prev site 0195 which is also present in Child Column
4. Then check Prev site 0197 which is not present in Child Column
5. so it should give last matched Child which is 0195 as the "output" in new column "Active Parent".
6. This should be done for all item in Child and find highest active

   Parent_Hierarchy<- c("0077_8239_0218", "0077_72597","0159_0162_0232", "0006_0042_72561", "0077_0090_0125", "0077_8239_0218_0184", "0197_0195_0192", "0197_2031_2414", "0159_2384", "0197_2247_2248_72769", "0197_0195_0192_0190", "0197_2247_2248")

   Child<-c("0218", "72597", "0232", "72561", "0125", "0184", "0195", "2414", "2384", "72769", "0190", "2248")

   Position <- c(3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3)

   Tree<- data.frame(Parent_Hierarchy,Child, Position)
   Tree$list<-strsplit(as.character(Tree$Parent_Hierarchy), split="[_]")

Below I am able to get the top parent in prev1 column but i want it programmatically like a loop.

```
#for getting prev1

Tree$prev1<-0
for (aa in 1:NROW(Tree$Position)) {
  ifelse(((Tree$Position[[aa]]>2)&&(Tree$list[[aa]]   [Tree$Position[[aa]]-2]) %in% Tree$Child),
     Tree$prev1[aa]<- as.character(Tree$list[[aa]][(Tree$Position[aa]-2)]),
     Tree$prev1[aa]<- as.character(Tree$Child[[aa]]))
}


#for getting prev2
Tree$prev2<-0

for (aa in 1:NROW(Tree$Position)) {
ifelse(((Tree$Position[[aa]]>3)&&(Tree$list[[aa]][Tree$Position[[aa]]-3]) %in% Tree$Child),
     Tree$prev2[aa]<- as.character(Tree$list[[aa]][(Tree$Position[aa]-3)]),
     Tree$prev2[aa]<- as.character(Tree$prev1[[aa]]))
}
```

#### I tried this solution but its looping for long time

```
for (aa in 1:NROW(poly_IDA$label2)) {
for (ii in poly_IDA$label2[[aa]]) {
while((poly_IDA$list[[aa]][(poly_IDA$label2[aa]-ii+1)] %in% poly_IDA$FromSite)){
  ifelse((poly_IDA$label2[[aa]]>ii),poly_IDA$prev3[aa]<-     poly_IDA$list[[aa]][(poly_IDA$label2[aa]-ii)],
         poly_IDA$prev3[aa]<- poly_IDA$list[[aa]][(poly_IDA$label2[aa]-ii+1)])
    }     
  }
}
```

pls let me know if you have any question

Comment: hope its not too complex for experts here, anyway waiting for someone to try, but i see i can use combination of above prev1 and prev2 upto max hieght and gather it back to final column.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not complex but the working and explanation is complex. I have tried to infer the meaning to the best of ability. I hope I am not wrong.

I am appending a solution. I hope it helps. You may want to try the code appended hereunder. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
    Parent_Hierarchy<- c("0077_8239_0218", "0077_72597","0159_0162_0232", "0006_0042_72561", "0077_0090_0125", "0077_8239_0218_0184", "0197_0195_0192", "0197_2031_2414", "0159_2384", "0197_2247_2248_72769", "0197_0195_0192_0190", "0197_2247_2248")
Tree<- data.frame(Parent_Hierarchy)
Tree$list<-strsplit(as.character(Parent_Hierarchy), split="[_]")
Tree$length <- lengths(Tree$list)
#Extracting the current child in the Parent Hierarchy
for (i in 1:NROW(Tree$list)){
  Tree$Child[i]<-Tree$list[[i]][Tree$length[i]]
}
#Extracting last Active Parent from Parent Hierarchy
for (i in 1:NROW(Tree$list)){
    print(i)
    for (j in seq(Tree$length[i])){
      print(c(j,Tree$length[i]-j+1))
      print(Tree$list[[i]][Tree$length[i]-j])
    ifelse((Tree$list[[i]][Tree$length[i]-j+1] %in% Tree$Child),Tree$activeP[i]<- Tree$list[[i]][Tree$length[i]-j],Tree$TopP[i]<- Tree$list[[i]][Tree$length[i]-j+1])
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bharat good try appreciate it, what are you getting in activeP should be present in Child column else it should be previous parent and so on

Comment: any other vectorized method anyone can suggest to speed it up

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution though not the best R way but does job nicely

```
#building the DF
Parent_Hierarchy<- c("0077_8239_0218", "0077_72597","0159_0162_0232", "0006_0042_72561", "0077_0090_0125", "0077_8239_0218_0184", "0197_0195_0192", "0197_2031_2414", "0159_2384", "0197_2247_2248_72769", "0197_0195_0192_0190", "0197_2247_2248")
Child<-c("0218", "72597", "0232", "72561", "0125", "0184", "0195", "2414", "2384", "72769", "0190", "2248")
Position <- as.numeric(mapply(grep,Tree$Child,Tree$list))
Tree<- data.frame(Parent_Hierarchy,Child, Position) 
Tree$list<-strsplit(as.character(Tree$Parent_Hierarchy), split="[_]")
Tree$activeP<-NA

#looping for extracting active parent
for (aa in 1:NROW(Tree$Position)) {
  ii=Tree$Position[[aa]]
  while(Tree$list[[aa]][ii] %in% Tree$Child){
    Tree$activeP[[aa]]<- Tree$list[[aa]][ii]
    ii=ii-1
  }
}
```